# Problem in DATE AND TIME

Tags: php, timezone

I am using date() function it getting the date and time as per my given format but the time its showing me is 4 hours forward than my current local machine time:
This is my code

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time());
```

Its showing me :             2009-10-28 08:47:42
Where as it should Disply :  2009-10-28 04:47:42

Any Idea whats wrong with this and why its showing different time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is likely giving you GMT, you need to set your timezone: e.g. `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I am in Kuala Lumpur Malaysia so what should be my time zone .

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your time zone is set correctly:

e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: That's likely to perpetuate the problem - using that value.  However, setting the default time zone to an appropriate value is correct (just UTC is probably not correct).

Comment: Agreed. The timezone the author sets would be whatever is correct for their application.

Answer (score 2):

It's returning the timezone of your server, not your computer

try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in, probably, US/Eastern (America/New_York, currently EDT) time zone, but the PHP you are using is running in UTC.  You need to ensure that the TZ variable is set in the PHP environment.